# Gambler’s Ruin Problem: how to calculate different probabilities?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, gambling

I need to resolve a gambler's ruin problem so I have been looking into problem number 5 in the following pdf, which is similar to mine and it is resolved:

[https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~fuchang/StochasticModel/Review3Solution.pdf](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Efuchang/StochasticModel/Review3Solution.pdf)

> Consider the gambler’s ruin problem with p = 0.6 and n = 4. Starting in state 2. Find:

First, they create Q, the matrix that describes the probability of transitioning from some transient state to another. What is a submatrix of the transition matrix

$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & .6 & 0 \\
.4 & 0 & .6 \\
0 & .4 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, they calculate the matrix that let us know the expected number of times the chain is in state j, given that the chain started in state i.

$$
(I-Q)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1.4615 & 1.1538 & 0.6923\\
0.7692 & 1.9231 & 1.1538\\
0.3077 & 0.7692 & 1.4615 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

> ...

> (b) the probability of ever visiting state 1

> the probability of ever visiting state 1 is 0.7692/1.4615 = 0.5263

Why is this division supposed to return the probability of ever visiting state 1?

The exercise in the pdf does not have such as section, but I would also need to calculate the expected number of visits to state 3 but **in the first 2 transitions**. Any hint?

Comment: For (a), notice that the (2,3) entry of $(I-Q)^{-1}$ is also 1.1538. The question mentions that you start in state 2.

Comment: @angryavian My fault. I edited the question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let $V_1$ denote the total number of visits to state 1. Write $E_i(V_1)$ for the mean of $V_1$ when the chain starts at state $i$. Write $A_1$ for the event that the chain ever reaches state 1. Then using the (strong) Markov property at the time of the first visit to state 1, we obtain
$$E_2(V_1)=P_2(A_1) E_2(V_1|A_1)=P_2(A_1)E_1(V_1) \,.$$
That explains why $P_2(A_1)$ is the  ratio $E_2(V_1)/E_1(V_1)$.

$----$

For your second question, using additivity of expectation, the expected number of visits to state 3 in the first two transitions (starting at state 2) is $Q(2,3)+Q^2(2,3)$. In the case of the given chain, the second summand vanishes and you obtain simply $Q(2,3)$.